# Imports after building ES module with webpack and babel are not highlighted in Intellij Idea

Tags: npm, intellij-idea, webpack, babeljs, node-modules

For future code maintenance, it is necessary to make the environment (in my case intellij idea 2021.1.3) highlight imports from custom modules of the internal working repository. The project uses a module passed through Babel, which is a set of exported functions that is loaded from the repository in node_modules, the file path looks like this:

```
project_name/node_modules/@modules/my-custom-module/dist/module.js
```

An example of an import in a project:

```
import { First, Second, Third } from '@modules/my-custom-module'
```

The Idea says 'cannot resolve symbol First' (and same with Second, Third)
It builds and works fine, but the idea doesn't see the functions themselves and the autocomplete doesn't work. At first I thought something was wrong with the builder, because in raw form, the code is imported normally and the functions are highlighted, perhaps this is the problem. A long search led me to alias, they can be configured in webpack, babel, package.json and you can create a root jsconfig.json file. The option with webpack did not fit, because. this did not affect the visibility of the environment, in fact, the usual customization of paths, for convenient perception. Now I'm trying jsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "modules/*": ["./node_modules/@modules/my-custom-module/dist/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

The idea does not react in any way, or I incorrectly indicate the path, or I am doing garbage, has anyone already faced a similar task?

Comment: I don't think that `jsoconfig.json` would help here, you need to set up the `"main":`, etc. fields of your `@modules/my-custom-module/package.json` to get your `.js` files resolved when importing modules from `@modules/my-custom-module`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out only after I created my module and uploaded it to github, it turns out that the modules are built together with sources that my colleagues did not add to git! Thus, the IDE perfectly pulls up imports, and after assembly, the transpiled code is located in the dist. What a stupid situation!

pacakge.json

```
{
  "name": "@modules/my-custom-module",
  "main": "dist/module.js",
  "esnext": "src"
  "files": [
    "README.md",
    "dist",
    "src"
  ],
}
```